# Codeblocks focus issue

Tags: unity, code-blocks

I am running CodeBlocks 16.01 in Ubuntu 16.04. A while back I reinstalled my OS and since then CodeBlocks no longer asks me to reload files edited by programs which are run from editor, even though the option "Check for externally modified files" is ticked in the settings. The only way to make that pop-up appear is to alt+tab out of CodeBlocks and then alt+tab back in it. I have installed CodeBlocks multiple times from different sources(Ubuntu Software Center, ppa:pasgui, ppa:damien-moore, codeblocks.org), with no success so far, the problem persists. All these things led me to believe that the issue is with the focus system of my OS, perhaps Unity is making problems.

The issue is similar to this one: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16224.0

I have also tried to do a dconf reset but that didn't help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it *could* be a problem with user watches. I had a similar issue with `ng serve` (Angular) failing to reload files I changed in IntelliJ until I increased the limit.

```bsh
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

The above command will work until you log out (so you can test if that was the issue). More information about what this is and how to make it permanent can be found here.

https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help, but thanks for the reply. Guess I have to look more into the problem